# Best Datagrid for Bootstrap/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datagrid

Been trying to Google for a while for a **nice, modern, datagrid** (not grid system) for Bootstrap or jQuery. Looked at GridUI(AngularJS) but it was very buggy, and looked at jQuery Bootgrid, but was wondering if any of you have experience with a solid one.

Comment: did you try JqGrid ?

Comment: Yea, it looks very old school. I'm looking for a datagrid with modern design.

Comment: can you show me an example ?

Comment: GridUI is nice. Anything like it?

Comment: can you please send me the link to that plugin ?

Comment: you can style the JqGrid to match with the GridUI style..

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) for a long time in a massive project, and it is a really good grid with a lot of features. It took me a long time to get to know the grid, but that was 3 years ago, and there were no wiki at all, so I guess it will be a lot simpler now when there's actually some documentation. I did find a fork created to work with bootstrap at https://github.com/reebalazs/SlickGrid-bootstrap but i have not tried it myself.

There are some limitations to how you can format it, but we have a totally white one with different themes that set row and menu colors etc.
Se this post for a very alternative style: [slickgrid styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262236/what-is-the-recommended-approach-to-style-a-slickgrid)

**EDIT:**

[ag-grid.com](http://ag-grid.com/) is a pretty new grid that was created to be as fast as **SlickGrid**, include more functionality and it works with **angular**. From what I could find, it should work with bootstrap aswell. I have not tested it yet, but it looks really nice and I'm thinking of using it in my next project.

Comment: stvowi recommends Gijgo in Bootgrid issue #369 on GitHub https://gijgo.com/grid